# 正規表現：全角文字またはローマ字・数字

Tags: javascript, 正規表現

[tokyo-wabisabi-boys.net](http://tokyo-wabisabi-boys.net/blog/javascriptjquery/js-string-regex-check)によると、全角文字に相当している正規表現は`/^[^\x01-\x7E\xA1-\xDF]+$/`です。「全角文字**または**ローマ字・数字(`\w`)」なら、どうでしょうか。`[^\x01-\x7E\xA1-\xDF]+|\w+`は確かに正しくありません。

Comment: ところで`/^[^\x01-\x7E\xA1-\xDF]+$/`ですとかなり適当で例えば半角カタカナが含まれていたりします。どの文字を**全角文字**とみなすか、そして期待通りの結果となっているのかきちんと確認することをお勧めします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

すでに承認された回答がついてしまっていますが、元記事の内容に間違いがありますので、念のため。

> 半角カナの文字コード範囲を表す正規表現『\xA1-\xDF』も指定に含めています。

と言う記述があるのですが、JavaScriptの文字列表現はUnicodeベースなので、`\xA1-\xDF`は半角カナではなくLatin-1 Supplement領域の`¡¢£¤...ÝÞß`なんて欧文用記号・アクセント記号つきアルファベットを表します。JavaScriptで半角カナの文字コード範囲を表したいなら、`\uFF61-\uFF9F`となります。

```
  //半角カナは除かないといけないのにtrueが返ってくる
  alert(/^[^\x01-\x7E\xA1-\xDF]+$/.test("ｱｲｳｴｵ")); //->true
  //この正規表現なら半角カナが「全角」と判定されることはない
  alert(/^[^\x01-\x7E\uFF61-\uFF9F]+$/.test("ｱｲｳｴｵ")); //->false
```

そもそもUnicode時代に何を持って「全角」「半角」と判定するのかは難しいところ(上記Latin-1 Supplementの文字は多くの等幅フォントで半角表示されます)で、ASCII互換文字(上記の例だと`\x00`や`\x7F`が抜けていますが)と半角カナ以外を「全角」と定義すると言うのはまぁありだと思うのですが、

> 全角文字に相当している正規表現は/^[^\x01-\x7E\xA1-\xDF]+$/です。

と言うのは **誤り** で、`/^[^\x01-\x7E\uFF61-\uFF9F]+$/`(または、`/^[^\x00-\x7F\uFF61-\uFF9F]+$/`)としなければなりません。

したがって、(上記部分以外はpgrhoさんの回答そのままですが)「全角文字またはローマ字・数字(\w)」なら`/^([^\x01-\x7E\uFF61-\uFF9F]|\w)+$/`(もしくは`/^([^\x00-\x7F\uFF61-\uFF9F]|\w)+$/`)ですね。

ほんの数行のテストコードを書いていれば気付けたはずなので、広く世間に晒すコードを書く場合にはもう少し気をつけて欲しいものです。

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> [^\x01-\x7E\xA1-\xDF]+|\w+
> ```

これは「全角文字列(`[^\x01-\x7E\xA1-\xDF]+`)または半角英数字文字列(`\w+`)」を表しており、両者を混在させることはできません。おそらく`([^\x01-\x7E\xA1-\xDF]|\w)+`が正しいのではないでしょうか。

またJavaScriptでの`\w`は文字コードでいえば`\x30-\x39`(数字)、`\x41-\x5a`(大文字)、`\xf` (_)、`\x61-\x7a` (小文字)に該当しますので、`\x01-\x7E`からこれらの区間を除外して`[^\x01-\x2f\x3a-\x40\x5b-\x5e\x60\x7b-\x7E\xA1-\xDF]+`とすることも可能です。

Comment: 素晴らしい回答に感謝致します。